# Solo me valida el primer array

Tags: php, login, validación

estoy haciendo un log in, tengo un archivo php llamado usuarios.php donde tengo unas constantes en un array con el correo y contraseña, pero la contraseña esta codificada en hash para luego verificar con la función **password_verify**.

Mi archivo php con las constantes es asi, obviamente las contraseñas y correos son inventados para comprobar:

```
<?php

    define('USUARIOS',array(
        array(
            'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
            'password' => convertir_hash('iloveu')    
        ),
        array(
            'email' => 'donald@donald.com',
            'password' => convertir_hash('m4k3Am3r1caGr3atAg41n')
        ),
        array(
            'email' => 'gilete@gilete.com ',
            'password' => convertir_hash('ErF4ryS1empr3')
        ),
        array(
            'email' => 'gon@gon.com ',
            'password' => convertir_hash('Fatality')
        ),
    )
    );

    function convertir_hash($pwd){
        return password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }
```

Luego en el php donde compruebo que esto sea correcto solo me valida el primero es decir si el usuario mete en el login admin@admin.com con la contraseña iloveu le redirecciona sin problemas, pero si hace cualquier otro correo y contraseña me salta el alert.

Asi es como lo tengo:

```
if(empty($errors)){
    foreach(USUARIOS as $vector){
       if($vector['email']===$email_Decod && password_verify($contra_Decod,$vector['password'])){
         header("location: principal.php");
         exit();
      }
   }
                        
   echo "<script language='javascript'> alert('El CORREO $email_Decod Y SON INCORRECTOS'); </script>";
   $errors = "ERROR:VUELVE A INTRODUCIR CORREO Y CONTRASEÑA!";
 }
```

email_Decod y contra_Decod son variables donde estan descodificados el correo ya que los codificaba con btoa en js y en php hago un base64_decode. El problema creo que el foreach no continua comprobando, pero no estoy seguro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primera instancia espero que hayas notado que los siguientes correos tienen un espacio al final:

- `'gon@gon.com '`
- `'gilete@gilete.com '`

Por lo que si el usuario coloca el mismo correo, pero sin el espacio al final, este no pasará la validación. Fuera de eso, he probado cada uno de los correos/contraseñas y ha pasado la valiación sin problemas.

```php
<?php

    define('USUARIOS',array(
        array(
            'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
            'password' => convertir_hash('iloveu')    
        ),
        array(
            'email' => 'donald@donald.com',
            'password' => convertir_hash('m4k3Am3r1caGr3atAg41n')
        ),
        array(
            'email' => 'gilete@gilete.com',
            'password' => convertir_hash('ErF4ryS1empr3')
        ),
        array(
            'email' => 'gon@gon.com',
            'password' => convertir_hash('Fatality')
        ),
    )
    );

    function convertir_hash($pwd){
        return password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }

    $email_Decod = 'gon@gon.com';
    $contra_Decod = 'Fatality';
    
    foreach(USUARIOS as $vector){
        if($vector['email']===$email_Decod && password_verify($contra_Decod,$vector['password'])){
            echo 'OK';
            // header("location: principal.php");
            exit();
        }
   }
   
   echo "<script language='javascript'> alert('El CORREO $email_Decod Y SON INCORRECTOS'); </script>";
   $errors = "ERROR:VUELVE A INTRODUCIR CORREO Y CONTRASEÑA!";
```

**EDIT:** Si no quieres un foreach para el login, puedes hacer uso de [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php) y poniéndolo en un función quedaría así:

```php
function login($email, $password) {
    $key = array_search($email, array_column(USUARIOS, 'email'));
        
    if (is_null($key)) return false;
        
    return password_verify($password, USUARIOS[$key]['password']);
}
```

Y las pruebas:

```php
$tests = array(
    array(
        'email' => 'noexiste@admin.com',
        'password' => 'incorrecto'
    ),
    array(
        'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
        'password' => 'iloveu'
    ),
    array(
        'email' => 'donald@donald.com',
        'password' => 'm4k3Am3r1caGr3atAg41n'
    ),
    array(
        'email' => 'gilete@gilete.com',
        'password' => 'ErF4ryS1empr3'
    ),
    array(
        'email' => 'gon@gon.com',
        'password' => 'Fataasdlity'
    ),
    array(
        'email' => 'gon@gon.com',
        'password' => 'Fatality'
    ),
);

foreach($tests as $test) {
    $login = login($test['email'], $test['password']) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
    echo "Email: {$test['email']}\n";
    echo "Login Status: {$login}\n\n";
}

# Salida:
# Email: noexiste@admin.com
# Login Status: FALSE

# Email: admin@admin.com
# Login Status: TRUE

# Email: donald@donald.com
# Login Status: TRUE

# Email: gilete@gilete.com
# Login Status: TRUE

# Email: gon@gon.com
# Login Status: FALSE

# Email: gon@gon.com
# Login Status: TRUE
```

Y aplicado a tu código:

```php
if (login($email_Decod, $contra_Decod)) {
    header("location: principal.php");
    exit();
}

echo "<script language='javascript'> alert('El CORREO $email_Decod Y SON INCORRECTOS'); </script>";
$errors = "ERROR:VUELVE A INTRODUCIR CORREO Y CONTRASEÑA!";
```

Comment: Totalmente cierto, no me había percatado de ese error. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Por nada, muchas veces son detalles que requieren de un segundo ojo. Agregué una opción para facilitar tu proceso de login, espero que te sea de utilidad.